# Что означает частица "да" в сочетании "да нет, наверное"?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Это сочетание кажется  **наиболее странным для иностранцев**, так как они отдельно считывают значение каждого слова. В действительности в речи отчетливо звучит ударное ***нет***, а остальные слова имеют второстепенное значение.

Со словом ***наверное*** все ясно, но что означает частица ***да***?

В словаре для нее нашлось такое определение: **ДА** 8. (в начале предл. или внутри его перед сказ., группой сказ.). Употр. для придания высказыванию **большей силы, выразительности.**  Да что с вами говорить! Да так оно обычно и бывает. Да кто вы такой, чтоб так задаваться? Да тебе-то что за дело? Куда идти? - Да прямо!

Частица в приведенных примерах **хотя и выразительная, но не очень вежливая.**

Допустим, вас спросили: "Придешь завтра?"  А вы отвечаете "Да нет, наверное". А если вы скажете "Да приду, наверное", то вас могут неправильно понять и даже обидеться. **Но вот почему, что с этой частицей не так?**

**И как определить значение частицы *ДА* в этом сочетании?**

Comment: По этимологии слова "да" идут споры, но в распространённых словарях рассматриваются не все значения — обсуждаемого я нигде не нашёл. Вероятно, существуют отдельные публикации, посвящённые этому слову, было бы интересно их посмотреть.

Comment: Почему могут обидеться на "да приду, наверно"? Во втором абзаце, может, лучше просто "означает"?

Comment: Спасибо, Артем.  Вы сами исправляйте, если что не так.

Comment: Я обычно и исправляю, просто не был до конца уверен, что Вы согласитесь с моей правкой. ;) Так а почему всё-таки могут обидеться?

Comment: Я  думаю, что могут. А Вы бы так ответили на этот вопрос?

Comment: Мог бы ответить так, да. У меня рождается сперва мысль, а потом формулируется в зависимости от настроения и от нюанса того, что я хочу выразить. Мог бы также ответить "скорее всего (приду)", "собираюсь", "очень хочу прийти (но не уверен, что получится)" и т. п.

Comment: Спасибо. Значит,  я буду знать, что, возможно, такой ответ не кажется обидным.

Comment: Всё зависит от интонации. Если ударение поставить на слово "приду" с паузой после него, тогда нет ничего обидного. И ответ будет означать, что "скорее всего приду, но не могу обещать". Если убрать паузу и чуть сместить интонационное ударение прозвучит как "пообещаю всё, что хочешь, только отстань".

Comment: Ударение здесь падает на "приду", и это "только отстань" мне ясно слышится, особенно если почитать примеры из словаря с этой частицей. А  в варианте: Куда идти? - Да прямо! - присутствует даже раздражение. И в большинстве приведенных примеров это невежливая, грубоватая частица.

Comment: Но  вот что странно: в сочетании  "да нет, наверное" она звучит вполне корректно и соответствует этикету. Это меня и удивляет.

Comment: В выражении "да прямо" у "да" другой смысл: "как куда?!" или "знамо/ясное дело!"

Answer (score 2):

Найти это значение можно перебором выражений для замещения частицы. На первый взгляд, близкий смысл имеет выражение "**точно не знаю, но...**", с контекстными вариациями ("не обещаю, но..." и т. п.).

Comment: А я собирался предложить замену на "пожалуй". Получается, "да" в таких выражениях имеет значение неуверенности, но в словарях об этом не говорится.

Comment: @grizzly  А вы не могли бы (пожалуйста) перенести комментарий в ответ, а то мне неудобно комментировать сразу два мнения. Спасибо.

Comment: @Alex_ander  Сомнение уже выражено вводным словом. Может быть  частица "да" это сомнение, наоборот, сводит на нет, то есть отвечающий уверен, что не придет.

Comment: @grizzly Я тоже сначала рассматривал "пожалуй", но вскоре заметил, что при прямой замене оно не сочетается с "наверное".

Comment: @Sharon Предложенная замена представляет собой типичный дипломатический вариант несогласия (он рекомендуется при аргументации в статьях, патентах и т. п.): "_ваш вопрос понятен, **но** не всё так просто_" - этого смысла нет в заключительном слове, выражающем только неуверенное предположение.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, во всех подобных выражениях "да" имеет значение неуверенности (усилитель неуверенности?) и может быть заменено по смыслу на "пожалуй", но в словарях об этом не говорится. Вот только интонационное построение фразы совсем другое, немного необычное для подобной модальности.

Comment: А я думаю, что во фразе "Да нет, наверное" сомнение отсутствует: наш герой точно знает, что не придет, хотя  и говорит для вежливости "наверное".  А  дословно, как я думаю, это можно перевести так: выбираю "нет" (утверждаю  отрицание с помощью  утвердительной частицы ДА). Но это просто моя версия, надо же как-то связать утверждение с отрицанием, а то что о нас иностранцы должны думать.

Comment: @Sharon Всё зависит от контекста и/или интонации. В случае ответа на приглашение я с Вами соглашусь — здесь влияет что-то "этикетное". Но если просто предложить кофе ("будешь кофе?"), то ответ "да нет, наверное" будет означать именно сомнение, а не уверенное "нет". Я бы счёл "этикетное" влияние вторичным.

Comment: А я думаю, что кофе он не будет. Сомнение только для вежливости. Иначе зачем здесь нужно это утвердительное "да".

Comment: @Sharon Судя по всем комментариям в этой теме мы действительно слегка по-разному воспринимаем/употребляем это выражение. В таком случае нет причин спорить; хорошо бы ещё статистику собрать по другим участникам.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваше мнение.  Я задала этот вопрос даже не лично для себя, мне просто не хочется думать, что в русском языке нет логики и мы ДА мешаем с НЕТ, что всех и  удивляет.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на противительный союз. Я бы назвал его - противительный смягчающий. 
- Да, как бы не так. 
- Да ну его, подальше!

Answer (score 0):

В словаре Ефремовой находим такое толкование:

> Употребляется при выражении раздумий, размышлений о чем-либо (обычно в
>   начале предложения).

Похожий случай — фраза «Да не знаю...», тут именно размышление, а не смягчение отказа (сравните с «Ну не знаю...», где пусть и вялое, но явное несогласие).

P.S. Раньше слово «наверное» выражало уверенность, так что конструкция «Да нет, наверное», если существовала в то время, могла восприниматься совершенно иначе, как железобетонный отказ :)

Comment: Пример употребления к этому пункту словарной статьи: "Да, были люди в наше время". В словаре имеется в виду именно такое употребление, и оно немного отличается от нашего случая во всех отношениях.

Comment: @grizzly, Вы ошибаетесь. В словаре Ефремовой примеров употребления вообще нет. Такой пример присутствует в словаре Ушакова, однако он приведён к другому значению: «В начале повествовательной речи употр. в знач.: так, действительно».

Comment: Я смотрю в словаре Кузнецова, но не в этом дело. В любом случае, употребление в этом значении требует определённой интонации и соответствующей пунктуации. В нашем случае ничего подобного нет.

Comment: В словаре Кузнецова значение несколько иное: «При выражении раздумья, **подведении итогов** каких-л. размышлений».

Comment: *Но не в этом дело.*

Comment: Расскажите подробнее об интонационных и пунктуационных несостыковках. Я их не вижу.

Comment: Вот если я скажу "Да-а, не знаю..." тогда это будет Ваше значение (здесь "а-а" не обязательно протяжное, но думаю, так будет понятнее). Ок, я выхожу из спора — вполне допускаю, что Вы действительно употребляете и понимаете так; просто имейте в виду, что это скорее исключение, чем правило.

Comment: По поводу «при выражении раздумья, подведении итогов каких-л. размышлений». Вы напрасно думаете, что запятая здесь означает "и", а не "или".

Comment: А я думаю, что это Ваш вариант — исключение. Стандартная ситуация: 
«— Пойдёшь на матч?
— Да не знаю... Столько дел на выходные».

Можно подставить «даже не знаю». Ничего общего с Вашим вариантом.
Раздумье и подведение итогов не одно и то же.

Comment: Я теперь понял, в чём Ваша ошибка. Вы полагаете, что цельное выражение "да не знаю" выражает размышление, а приписываете это размышление одной только частице "да". В Вашем понимании даже частица "даже" имеет значение размышления (сверьтесь с Ефремовой).

Comment: Никакой ошибки тут нет. «Да не знаю» явно выражает размышление, как и «даже не знаю», а вот «не знаю» или «ну не знаю» — нет.

Comment: Прочитайте ещё раз внимательно вопрос. Спрашивается не о значении выражений типа "да не знаю", а о значении одной только частицы "да" в этих выражениях. И после этого перечитайте последние два комментария. Всё, увольте.

Comment: А Вы перечитайте ветку и обратите внимание, на что я отвечал. Я в курсе, какой вопрос. И, на минуточку, дал на него очень чёткий ответ: привёл значение частицы из словаря.

Answer (score -1):

Ничего особенного не означает. 
Обычная усилительная частица. Путает её омонимичность с союзом, но на этой омонимичности все сложности и заканчиваются.

Я так понимаю, что здесь то же значение, что и в этих примерах.

8.(в начале предл. или внутри его перед сказ., группой сказ.). Употр. для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности. И я чего-нибудь да стою! Да что с вами говорить! Да так оно обычно и бывает. Да кто вы такой, чтоб так задаваться? Да тебе-то что за дело? Куда идти? - Да прямо! Вот это да! (выражает восхищение, одобрение). * Скажи, которая Татьяна? - Да та, которая грустна (Пушкин).

(БТС Кузнецова).

(+)========

Прочитал другие ответы... Странно всё это. Придется, видимо, изложить свою точку зрения подробнее... Но сейчас не смогу, попозже.

Comment: Что в нашем случае _усиливает_ частица - неуверенное отрицание?

Comment: @Alex_ander Все вместе.  Здесь нет как такового грамматического сказуемого, но семантическим сказуемым является вся конструкция №нет, наверное". Его и усиливает.  В русской грамматики не выделяют "сомнительных" частиц, а то бы вы были совершенно правы с вашей трактовкой.